# Depiction and thumbnail relationships in DBpedia

Tags: rdf, dbpedia, foaf

I have an earlier 2022 extraction of DBPedia and I am having a hard time finding even a fraction of the images/depictions/thumbnails present on the dbpedia.org resource pages. For example: https://dbpedia.org/page/John_F._Kennedy# has a thumbnail relationship as well as many depiction relationships, but in the data when I grep for thumbnail/depicts/depiction I get maybe 50 items for the whole extraction, and none for JFK. I can (and plan to) download the absolute latest dump and compare, but am I just doing something wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure if I understand, but if you find no more than the ~50 triples linking to images, then you might have downloaded the wrong or simply not all data of the DBpedia dump. I mean, how and what exactly did you download? The data should be available via Databus, no? Images should be in the images artifact, i.e. here: https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/generic/images/ - so, did you load that file as well?

Comment: note, a DBpedia dump is not a single file, but many managed in a so-called collection in the Databus, e.g. look at https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/collections/dbpedia-snapshot-2022-09/